# Active Admin uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I just migrated a Rails app to 3.1. Active Admin is now 0.6.0. That's my routes.rb

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "homepage#index"

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

So root is declared before ActiveAdmin routes. We I start the server in development and I reload the browser I get the ActiveAdmin interface here:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin
```

When I reload that URL I get:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found several issues:

1. assets generator must best execute after an update;
2. controllers/admin clashes with ActiveAdmin route;
3. root directive should be define before ActiveAdmin route.

To fix number one:

```
$> rails generate active_admin:assets
```

To fix number two:

```
config.default_namespace = :your_desired_namespace
```

To fix number three just move root up (in config/routes.rb)

Comment: that fixed a few thing for me but I am still getting a No route matches [GET] "/admin/authentications" ...  I used to have my own admin_controller but I had renamed it, so it should not conflict. Yet I have tried changing the namespace as you suggested, but still having the routing error. Any further ideas?

Comment: Since you renamed you admin controller I would not set config.default_namespace and see if you can access /admin. It must be a simple error. I would use 'bundle exec rake routes' and see the generated routes to understand where the problem is.